# LMC (ASM) Counting Loop

Tags: assembly, little-man-computer

LMC is a learning tool over @http://gcsecomputing.org.uk/lmc/index.html and a set of problems are "Write a program to output the numbers 1 to 10 in ascending order.

Write a program to output the numbers 1 to 10 in descending order."

Using the instruction set http://gcsecomputing.org.uk/lmc/instruction_set.html I was able to get this

```
loop LDA value1
OUT
SUB value2
STA value1
BRP loop

value1 DAT 10
value2 DAT 1
```

This counts from 10 to 0 but I can't figure out how to count upward to 10 and then stop counting. Any help solving these two problems would be very much appreciated.

Comment: It's the same program just print `11-x`

Comment: @Jester I feel silly for not thinking of that but thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Change the direction (`SUB` becomes `ADD`), change the start/end values (`value1`, `value2`) and perform a comparison with 10 (by doing a `SUB` and `BRP`) to detect whether the end value has been reached, and do this before incrementing.

Don't forget to add a `HLT` to your program, as you don't want the execution to continue in your data section.

I would also suggest using more meaningful variable names (`DAT` labels).

```html
start   LDA current
loop    OUT
        SUB until
        BRP exit
        LDA current
        ADD one
        STA current
        BRA loop
exit    HLT

current DAT 0
until   DAT 10
one     DAT 1

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/trincot/lmc@v0.6/lmc.js"></script>
```